# What is this fighter jet that flew over KJST?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This aircraft was doing low level flights over my office a few minutes ago.  From the route it was flying some of my coworkers thought it might have been doing approaches or touch and go landings at the local airport ([Johnstown, PA (KJST)](http://airnav.com/airport/KJST)).

[image]

After it left the area I tried comparing it against pictures of active US fighters; but the wings didn't appear to match with anything I saw.

Comment: What local airport? Could help to identify by knowing what air wings are stationed nearby. It looks like the YF-17 but only two were made and it never saw production after the initial 2 in 1974. Both aircraft are supposedly on display, one in Torrance California and one in Mobile Alabama. It is probably an F-18 variant though, the wings look a little different but it could just be perspective.

Comment: The fusilage's single curve does seem to fit the YF-17 better than an F-18.  I can't imagine what one would be doing around here though even if it was flying though.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's an [F/A-18 Super Hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_F/A-18E/F_Super_Hornet).

Defining characteristics:

- Slightly angled twin vertical tail
- Twin engine with little space between them (eliminating the F-14 and similar)
- Almost straight trailing edge of the wings
- Horizontal tail with significant sweep angle that also protrudes behind the engine exhaust
- Massive wing strakes (thanks Dan Pichelman!) along the fuselage under the cockpit
- The wing "notch", as noted by Ron Beyer in the comments

Also the shape of the horizontal tail excludes the YF-17:
[image: YF-17 vs Hornet]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Northrop_YF-17_and_McDonnell_Douglas_FA-18_top-view_silhouette_comparison.png)

As mentioned by Penguin, the wing notch, together with the single curve [leading edge extensions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33980/1696) are the indicators that mark this aircraft as a "Super" variant (E-F, single seat and two-seat, respectively) rather than an earlier vanilla "Hornet" variant (A-C), as seen in this figure:

[image: Hornet vs Super Hornet]

[Source](http://thanlont.blogspot.de/2011_04_01_archive.html)

Note also the less round profile of the horizontal tail, like the one seen in OP's photo.